# using strstr() function is breaking

Tags: c++, c

I am using `strstr()` function but I am getting the crash.

This part of code is crashing with error "**Access violation reading location 0x0000006c.**"
 `strstr(p_czCharactersToDelete, (const char*)p_czInputString[index]))`

Here is the complete code...

```
#include "stdafx.h"    
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
void delchar(char* p_czInputString, const char* p_czCharactersToDelete)
{
    for (size_t index = 0; index < strlen(p_czInputString); ++index)
    {
        if(NULL != strstr(p_czCharactersToDelete, (const char*)p_czInputString[index]))
        {
            printf_s("%c",p_czInputString[index]);

        }
    }
}
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char c[32];
    strncpy_s(c, "life of pie", 32); 
    delchar(c, "def");

    // will output 'li o pi'
    std::cout << c << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Which language, C or C++ ?

Comment: You are casting a character value (`p_czInputString[index]`) to a pointer. When you need to cast, you should think carefully why you're cheating the compiler.

Comment: It seems like C++ code but you didn't used "namespace std". Probably it is not the problem you are asking for but it seems a bit awkward to me. Does it compile correctly?

Comment: should probably be strstr(p_czCharactersToDelete, (const char*)&p_czInputString[index]))

Comment: I think what Md. Taufique is trying to tell you is that you should be using `std::string` instead of C-style strings. Good advice; you should listen.

Comment: In case it wasn't clear enough from previous comments: DON'T RANDOMLY ADD CASTS TO YOUR CODE TO MAKE IT COMPILE. Of course it's crashing, because when the compiler told you your code was wrong you thought it would be better to tell it to shut up instead of fixing the problem. If you'r confused by how casting works, here's a good rule of thumb: try with a `static_cast<>` first, and if (as in this case) that's not good enough and it would take a `reinterpret_cast<>` to get the compiler to accept your code, then you have no excuse and it really must be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The prototype of `strstr()` is as follows,

```
char * strstr ( char * str1, const char * str2 );
```

The function is used to locate substring from a main string. It returns a pointer to the first occurrence of `str2` in `str1`, or a null pointer if `str2` is not part of `str1`.

In your case you are passing the wrong parameters to the `strstr()`. You are calling, 
`strstr(p_czCharactersToDelete, (const char*)p_czInputString[index]));`, which is wrong. Because the pointer `p_czCharactersToDelete` points to the sub string constant and `p_czInputString` points to the main string. Call `strstr()` as `strstr(p_czInputString, p_czCharactersToDelete);` and make corresponding changes in the function `delchar()`.

Comment: HI thanks for your reply.what i Intnded to with function delchar() is that all the alphabets present p_czCharactersToDelete should be removed from p_czInputString. 
The way you suggesting will not give me the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

you are using the wrong `strstr`.
 probably you need `strchr` or `strpbrk`.

```
#include <cstring>
#include <algorithm>

class Include {
public:
    Include(const char *list){ m_list = list; }

    bool operator()(char ch) const
    {
        return ( strchr(m_list, ch) != NULL );
    }

private:
    const char *m_list;
};

void delchar(char* p_czInputString, const char* p_czCharactersToDelete){
    Include inc(p_czCharactersToDelete);
    char *last = std::remove_if(p_czInputString, p_czInputString + strlen(p_czInputString), inc);
    *last = '\0';
}
```

Comment: HI,
Thanks for your reply.
What i intend to do with function delchar() is that all the alphabets present p_czCharactersToDelete should be removed from p_czInputString. 
The way you suggesting will not give me the desired result.
Problem, was that inside function strstr() the first parameter is getting the right value but the second parameters is getting some corrupted address...So, something is wrong with the way p_czCharactersToDelete is being passed...

Comment: @BhupeshPant I seem your understanding as only poor.

Comment: I will totally agree with your statement if you can solve my problem...I know you are not like me and can solve this...Cheersss!!!